# Paypal Adaptive Pay

Tags: php, paypal

When I run a PayPal Adaptive Pay call, and I set about 3 receivers, how to I get the status of each of the receivers?

Because I get something back like this:

```
Array
(
    [responseEnvelope.timestamp] => 2012-11-05T13:17:48.598-08:00
    [responseEnvelope.ack] => Success
    [responseEnvelope.correlationId] => 8e31ecdad58ca
    [responseEnvelope.build] => 4110101
    [payKey] => AP-6TJ00518SC231111B
    [paymentExecStatus] => COMPLETED
)
```

Does this go through the IPN or can I view it in a sandbox area? I keep re-reading PayPal docs and Im so confused :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use [PaymentDetails](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APPaymentDetails) api to obtain an array of PaymentInfo elements with status for each receiver. If you have permissions from each recipients to make GetTransactionDetails API calls on-behalf of them (which you can obtain using Permissions API) you can use the TransactionID from the PaymentDetails API response to obtain further more transactional data for each one of the sub-transactions.

Comment: Thanks man this is it. I might actually use Mass Pay, I recently read this is limited to 6 users per call and I need many more than that, but Ill keep this remembered.